# Primefaces ConfirmDialog not vertically centered in form updated with ajax

Tags: java, html, jsf, primefaces

I have a form that "grows" through Ajax+Rendered when some operations are clicked. The problem is that my p:confirmDialog is not vertically centered when the form grows. When in "normal size", the dialog is correctly centered.

I have already tried:

- Remove or add "appendToBody" attribute
- Change the position of the declaration in the page (before and after h:form)
- Overwrite the "Top" in CSS

Is that an issue from Primefaces (currently using v4) or am I doing something wrong? Since I use lots of "rendered" attributes, should I "rerender" the dialog?

Here follows a snippet of my code.

```
<h:form id="myForm">            
    <p:fieldset legend="Hello">
        <!-- lots of things here -->
    </p:fieldset>
    <p:spacer height="20px" />
    <p:fieldset legend="Dashboard" 
        id="thisOneMakesTheFormGrows" 
        rendered="#{bean.include or bean.edit}">
        <!-- this one has lots of items, making the page grow when the 'rendered' attribute is true -->
    </p:fieldset>
</h:form>           

<p:confirmDialog global="true"
    id="meuConfirmDlg"
    appendToBody="true"
    showEffect="fade"
    width="500px" 
    hideEffect="fade"
    widgetVar="confirmDlg"
    closable="false">
    <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
    <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
</p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you overwritten the TOP attribute of the dialog box by percentage? If not please overwrite the css of the dialog box div.

```
#dialogBoxId{
 top: 50% !important;
 left:50% !important;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Only had to remove the "left" attribute, because it rendered the dialog on the right portion of the screen.