# How to change the position of confirmation box in jsf primefaces?

Tags: javascript, css, jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces confirmation box in JSF. The dialog is getting pop up at the end of the page but i want it to get pop up at the center of the page.
on checking with inspect element in browser I am getting below html code whcih shows the dilog box by default have inline CSS defined. I tried to give css to its class but its not working .

[image: html code of the confirmation box]

**JSF Code :**

```
<p:confirmDialog message= "Do you want to save your changes?"   showEffect="fade" widgetVar="Confirm" position="center"> 

<p:commandButton value="Yes" action="#{emdNew.save}" oncomplete="PF('Confirm').hide()" update=":form"/>

<p:commandButton value="No"  update="@form"  immediate="true" action="#{emdNew.no}" oncomplete="PF('Confirm').hide()" /> 

</p:confirmDialog>
```

Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces ConfirmDialog not vertically centered in form updated with ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26740262/primefaces-confirmdialog-not-vertically-centered-in-form-updated-with-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `appendTo`-attribute to define the element on which the `<p:confirmDialog>` should be centered. I would try using the following value:

```
<p:confirmDialog appendTo="body" ...></p:confirmDialog>
```

Another approach would be to override the default styling of the `.ui-dialog` class:

```
.ui-class {
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
}
```

Be careful to include your custom stylesheet after default PrimeFaces CSS.

I can't test this atm but I hope this helps you solve your issue. Have a look at the [docs](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_2.pdf) for further information.

Comment: Hi Lars, thank you for your response. I tried appendTo="@(body)" its not working for me.  other way - .ui-class also not working :(

Answer (score 0):

If you use `confirmDialog` in form, you need to write like this;

```
/*This code for dialog component*/

#formID\:dialogID {
  left: 5% !important;
  top: 15% !important;
}

/*This code for confirmDialog component*/

.ui-dialog {
  left: 5% !important;
  top: 15% !important;
}
```

but be careful using `.ui-dialog`.